# Turn hiccup into html in a reagent application

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, hiccup

This might sound a stupid question, but how do I turn a piece of hiccup into html in a ClojureScript reagent application?

I want something like this :

```
(html [:div [:p "hello world" ]])
```

that produces

```
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
```

This is what you can do in hiccup.core, but as far as I can see, that's in Clojure. Not ClojureScript in the browser.

OTOH, ClojureScript / Reagent clearly knows how to do it in the browser. It's doing it all the time. But I can't actually find a library call anywhere in reagent where I can do this explicitly, outside the reagent rendering process.

Comment: also give a look at: https://github.com/buttercloud/html2hiccup (You need it in apposite direction :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but it appears one answer is to use the function:

- [reagent.dom.server/render-to-string](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0/api/reagent.dom.server#render-to-string)

Normally, your **Reagent components only return Hiccup data**, and you let `reagent.dom/render` do all the hard work of reactively "rendering" only the changed components into the DOM.

---

P.S.  When in doubt, you can often find documentation at [cljdoc.org](https://cljdoc.org/). Most Clojure projects have a direct link there from their GitHub page ([Reagent does](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent), for example).  Or, you can go to cljdoc.org directly and search there.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, that's it. I want to do it because I'm generating the html dynamically in the code that's running in the browser.